# Sending messages between Android Wear & Mobile?

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm writing an app which sends a predefined message to a predefined number.  It then gets the response and displays this to the user.  I've got the mobile side working, and I am now working on the Wear app, however have become a little stuck as to how to do it.

I've managed to send the message from the Wear device by implementing a listener on the mobile app, which then triggers the activity to send a message.  What I can't figure out how to do, is that the response the app gets and send it back to the Wear device.

Looking here:https://developer.android.com/training/wearables/data-layer/index.html

I have used the MessagesAPI for sending the message, however unsure what to use if I want to receive a message.  Does anyone know what the best way to do this would be?  My initial instinct says I'm going to have to ditch the messagesApi and use the Data one?

Answer (score 1):

You should send the response the same way you used to send the first message, but this time the wearable will be listening for messages (usually in your WearableListenerService).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this: https://github.com/heinrisch/talkclient

Either you can use the library or look at the code. I would look at the code, its quite easy to follow.

It sounds like you can use either data or message api, depending on your needs. To receive a message you either have the app active and get it though a listener, or you create a service.